# pixielabs deploy stuck Wait for PEMs/Kelvin

Tags: kubernetes

After installing [pixielabs](https://pixielabs.ai) with the bash-installer and deploying with `px deploy`, this deployment got stuck (over 30min) with:

```
Wait for PEMs/Kelvin
```

After aborting I got an new namespace `pl` with many pods pending or in Init.
But no working pixielab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the `etcd` pod in the `pl` namespace is in `pending` state.

The Pixie Command Module is deployed in the K8s cluster to isolate data storage, therefore you'll need a persistent volume in your cluster.